# Inheriting and __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter

I created my own class which is basically the same as `Button` from **tkinter** but I want to change a few things.
I need to redefine the `__init__` method so that it does everything the **Button**`__init__` method does but I want to add some stuff like append the instance to the list of students. so I used `super().__init__()` but I have no idea what goes inside of the brackets. I know the basics of inheritance from youtube tutorials but inheriting from the Button class seems more comlicated. I tried copying some stuff from the Button class from tkinter module but i still get errors. How do i fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Student(Button):
    students = []

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf, kw)
        Student.students.append(self)


enrique = Student(root, padx=30, pady=10, text="Enrique", fg="#000000", bg="#00FFFF" )
enrique.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()


>>>TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `Button` to see what its `__init__` expects?

Comment: The code in the question does not produce that error. Please edit your question and provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: There, I changed it up a bit. That's the error I get now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `**` from `kw`:

```py
class Student(Button):
    students = []

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        Student.students.append(self)
```